# Change value in xml tree having a tag that matches particular regex patterm

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to xsl and I am stuck with a problem.

I have a xml like:

```
<abc>
    <def>
        <ghi>
            <hello:abcXYZ>1</hello:abcXYZ>
            <hello:defXYZ>10</hello:defXYZ>
            <hello:defXYZ>11</hello:defXYZ>
            <hello>5<hello>
        </ghi>
    </def>
</abc>
```

I want to have a template match in xsl so that for a tag in tree "abc/def/ghi", matches pattern 'hello*XYZ' (starts with 'hello' and ends with 'XYZ'), the value inside should get replaced by zero.

This way the output xml will be like:

```
<abc>
    <def>
        <ghi>
            <hello:abcXYZ>0</hello:abcXYZ>
            <hello:defXYZ>0</hello:defXYZ>
            <hello:defXYZ>0</hello:defXYZ>
            <hello>5<hello>
        </ghi>
    </def>
</abc>
```

Can anybody please help. Thanks.

Comment: You've tagged your question with _both_ XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 - which one of the two do you actually require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well assuming XSLT 2.0 it is not that difficult to translate your description into a regular expression pattern and into a match pattern:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="pattern" select="'hello.*XYZ'"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="abc/def/ghi/*[matches(name(), $pattern)]">
  <xsl:copy>0</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms

```
<abc xmlns:hello="http://example.com/">
    <def>
        <ghi>
            <hello:abcXYZ>1</hello:abcXYZ>
            <hello:defXYZ>10</hello:defXYZ>
            <hello:defXYZ>11</hello:defXYZ>
            <hello>5</hello>
        </ghi>
    </def>
</abc>
```

into

```
<abc xmlns:hello="http://example.com/">
    <def>
        <ghi>
            <hello:abcXYZ>0</hello:abcXYZ>
            <hello:defXYZ>0</hello:defXYZ>
            <hello:defXYZ>0</hello:defXYZ>
            <hello>5</hello>
        </ghi>
    </def>
</abc>
```

Comment: Any way I can do it with XSLT 1?

Comment: If you change `match="abc/def/ghi/*[matches(name(), $pattern)]"` to `match="abc/def/ghi/*[starts-with(name(), 'hello') and substring(name(), string-length(name()) - 2) = 'XYZ']"` you have a pattern that should work with XSLT 1.0